# Javafx. Bug with TitledPane

Tags: javafx

Now I'm working with javafx and create small view with SplitPane. 
In this SplitPane i have two TiteledPanes(named A and B). At first step of program working, only one TitledPane contains data (A). But after little user actions some information are put on B. 
If i run my programm 10 times, at 7-8 times everything will be ok! 
But in 2 times I have a problem with second titeledPane. It is consists with no data. This TitledPane loaded without any exceptions and all bindings are good, But it consists with no data. It is very strange, because in 80% of time everything is ok.

May be this is javafx bugs? 
Any one have the same problem?

```
<fx:root type="MyView" dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL" style="-fx-background-color: darkgray">
    <fx:define>
        <TitledPane fx:id="A">
           <AnhorPane>
            <Label text="ALabel"/>
           </AnhorPane>
        </TitledPane>
        <TitledPane fx:id="B"/>
           <AnhorPane>
               <Label text="BLabel"/>
           </AnhorPane>
        </TitledPane>
    </fx:define>
</fx:root>




public class MyView extends SplitPane {
public MyView () {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MyView .fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide a short, complete example which demonstrates this behavior? (See "How to create a [MCVE]".)

Comment: It's very simple example which i have written. But about 2 of 10 iterations of programm running ends with empty B TiteledPane

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in loading fxml file proccess. There are a lot of data should be loaded after the load fxml file(in my model class relating to that fxml) and in future adding to existing fxml. Like binding properties and etc.

When I relocate above 80% of bindings in fxml file using ${} - the problem was solded.